# Does the generic type not apply constraint inside the body of a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, syntax-checking, typed

I'm sure if this is possible, I'm beginner in TypeScript but what I'm trying to do is:

I have the following `type`;

```
type Special<C> = {
    [Prop in keyof C]: C[Prop] extends Function | string ? C[Prop] : never;
}
```

There can only be properties of type `string` and `Function`, therefore, if there is a property of type `number`,`Array`, etc., it will produce an error:

```
class A {
    public msg: string = 'Hello!';
    public test() {}
}

const a: Special<A> = new A(); // Ok!
```

But:

```
class B {
    public msg: string = 'Hello World!';
    public Run() {}
    public num: number = 123;
}

const b: Special<B> = new A(); // Error!, Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

If I try to do the same inside the body of a function, the type checking is not done:

```
type Class<ClassType = any, constructorParams = any> = {
    new (...agrs: Array<constructorParams>): ClassType;
};

class A {
    public msg: string = 'Hello!';
    public test() {}
    public num: number = 123;
}

const Testing = <T>(controller: Class<T>) => {
    const a: Special<typeof controller> = new controller(); // is Ok!???
};

Testing(A); // is Ok!???
```

The only thing I was able to achieve was something like this to get the type checking to work:

```
class A {
    public msg: string = 'Hello!';
    public test() {}
    public num: number = 123;
}

const Testing = <T>(controller: Class<Special<T>>) => {
    const a = new controller(); 
};

Testing(A); // // Error!, Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

How can I achieve type checking of "Special " inside the body of the `Testing` function?

Am I doing something wrong? Am I not understanding something that is missing?

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: In your `Testing` function, when you do `Special<typeof controller>`, you're essentially doing `Special<Class<T>>`, substitute `T` with `A` (your class), and you get `Special<Class<A>>`, of course - since `Class<A>` just contains the constructor function, `Special<Class<A>>` evaluates to an empty object (`{}`). TS allows assigning objects with potentially more properties to an empty object in this case. And there you go.

Comment: You probably want to reach something along the lines of `Special<A>` after `T` substitution.

Comment: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAhgGwDwGEB8UC8UA3gLABQUFUA2gAoBOA9mFIgHZQDWEIDAZlJgC6ALgG1GYQVAgAPYBFYATAM5QAYgFdW8YIgbsAPlGXA6bAOZQA-GPpMpo1hABuEOgG4yAXzJlQkAVRkZWUsIJCAFXBoAmRWEAAaKHh9EzoNHQY6GmQ6ZABbVVj43AISckonAHcoAAoAOkbkczplUQBBOjyQdBTWNIzgLJy8wuwASlFMcOUoyE9SLwWyeBmodqIySigwDQAjVER4KELzUTSLfCgAcgAJCFRUBgBCa4Xt3YOjqHkTWvGiD4KhRPodjqwNPlHJC9m4rgBGABMAGYFkCyLwtDo9OxfrpWOZ0BFsLU+qYGI83FMZkSJptgclUsAoMhRHAIEg0LSrtVGaxyZS6P93pQAPSiqAAPSgAFEullVAwNMAkso2PBoAADCKak6IcwAC2ZrAYzLQVWQIFUsJ+BugygK0GCUE17M5GGJmvq3gWQA)

Comment: @Chase Is there any way that the check is triggered from `testing(A)`?, So when any class is passed, it can be verified.

Comment: Do you want  `controller` to be an object with only `stirng` and `function` properties? What errors do you expect? dn dont expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it looks like you want the error to be raised in `testing`'s call site. That essentially means that you *must* constraint the type of the argument `testing` can take in. And you should constrain it in a way so that the instance returned by a class constructor, is assignable to `Special`.

Ok, the bearings you've already provided-

```
type Special<C> = {
    [Prop in keyof C]: C[Prop] extends Function | string ? C[Prop] : never;
}
```

And here's the class that *must not* pass without error-

```
class A {
    public msg: string = 'Hello!';
    public test() {}
    public num: number = 123;
}
```

Here's a similar class that *should* pass without error-

```
class B {
    public msg: string = 'Hello!';
    public test() {}
}
```

Ok, now here's the description of your `testing` function-

#### Preliminary

It takes in a class constructor as its argument.

#### Declaration

Let `T` be the type of the instance constructed by said class constructor.

#### Constraint

`T` must be assignable to `Special<T>`

#### Implementation

The way you constraint `T` to be assignable to `Special<T>` is by using `T extends Special<T>` clause in your function. Combine everything from above, and you get-

```
function testing<T extends Special<T>>(controller: new (...args: any[]) => T) {
    const a: Special<T> = new controller();
};
```

Nothing too special that hasn't already been discussed. I got rid of your `Class` type since I just wrote that type inline- `new (...args: any[]) => T`. Note the `T` there. That's the instance type.

Now you'll get an error on `testing(A)` but not with `testing(B)`. The error you get is-

> Argument of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => Special'.
> Construct signature return types 'A' and 'Special' are incompatible.
> The types of 'num' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Check it out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAhgGwDwGEB8UC8UA3gLABQUFUA2gAoBOA9mFIgHZQDWEIDAZlJgC6ALgG1GYQVAgAPYBFYATAM5QAYgFdW8YIgbsAPlGXA6bAOZQA-GPpMpo1hABuEOgG4yAXzJl4qZGVVAEEiMkooMA0AI1REeCgAW2VzURMzVksCAHIACQhUVAYAQmzPckoo2PioeRMACgBKIh8Kiiq4hNYNRMce6Ld8KABGACYAZnLWvwCgqAAhMLbImM6klLTTCyG8gqLS8oiOmrrgJpbvX1JeLR09dlOLdAAVaTkFFVgEFAxn7Gx6vB9KYGIU3I4IAB3KD1AB08OQdHMylEyFYICogmaeFwz2aJGWQNYJigyFEcAgSDQL1wBCc0KJILBdCaU3KZEemXqwUa7NInPM9XmvLIQA)